# Determine closure and interior of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine closure and interior of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$

Definitions: A set is open iff for every point $x \in A$ we have a neighbourhood such that U(x) $\subset A$. $cl(A):=$ smallest possible closed set which contains A, $int(A):=$ biggest possible open set which is a subset of $A$

What I already could show is that closure of the ratoinals is equals to the reals and interor of the rationals is the empty set. The closure of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$ and the interior of $(0,1)$ is the set itself. Thus we find interior of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)=$ $int(\mathbb{Q}) \cap int((0,1))=\emptyset$. But I can't apply the same trick for the closure. Any hints?

Comment: In your title, you speak of $[0,1]$ but in your question, you consider  $(0,1)$. Can you edit your post?

Comment: In the title, did you mean interior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  The closure includes every point you can reach to as the limit of sequences from your subset.   What points can you approximate arbitrarily closely with a sequence of rationals between 0 and 1?